# ERROR: could not serialize access due to concurrent update once trying to update data to the same records of parent in threaded function

Tags: multithreading, odoo, odoo-14

I'm trying to apply some customize once stock.move done and make it run in background due to performance issue of validating picking so multi thread is solution. But I'm in trouble with updating data in the same row:

```
def _action_done(self, cancel_backorder=False):

    res = super(StockMove, self)._action_done(cancel_backorder=cancel_backorder)

    if res:

        if res.filtered(lambda x: x.state == 'done'):

            threaded_calculation = threading.Thread(

                            target=self.sync_fulfillment_stats,

                            args=(res.filtered(lambda x: x.state == 'done').ids))

            threaded_calculation.setDaemon(True)

            threaded_calculation.start()


def sync_fulfillment_stats(self, move_ids):

    # sleeping time to make sure quantity done is already saved

    time2.sleep(3)

    with api.Environment.manage(), self.pool.cursor() as new_cr:

        self = self.with_env(self.env(cr=new_cr))



        moves = self.env['stock.move'].search(

            [('id', 'in', move_ids)])

        for move in moves:

​   ​move.sync = True   ........
```